# OpenBox folder label color changing?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, label, openbox

I'm currently struggling agaist a little irritating thing - I'm new to Linux overall, I have Arch Linux installed and Openbox for GUI. I'd like to change folder label (names) colors - they are grey in default and hard to see on white background. I've been looking for any options for it both in xml files and configuring 'themerc' files of distinct themes, but all of the color options I changed didn't work on the one I wanted.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...
Right click on the desktop -> Applications --> Settings --> Customize the look and feel.